# E-mails send by Amazon SES are received multiple times in @icloud.com mailboxes

Tags: amazon-ses

We are sending transactional e-mail to multiple e-mail domains. At the moment we are experiencing issues with @icloud.com mailboxes. They receive the same e-mail multiple times. The strange thing however is, the e-mail is only once in the mailbox, but every 20 minutes or so it is received again, until it stops after approximately 10 times.

I have no idea if this is a iCloud issue or Amazon SES issue. More people experiencing the same issue or would anyone know what I can do to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the SendRawEmail API when sending the e-mails. It finally found out that some e-mails had this issue. I also did not receive a delivery notification for these e-mails. I think the issue was the HTML body's getting to big.

I found out that e-mails with attachement or small body had no issues. Tried to send the e-mails with issues as RAW and then they had no issues. It is strange why this is an issue since this week.